# Where/how does Windows store the data in the event logs?

Tags: windows, windows-event-log

We run some financial systems that log error messages to the system logs. I need to find out if we can clean these error messages from a PCI DSS point of view.

I am specificaly interested in the answer for:

- Windows 2000 Server and
- Windows 2003 SP1

Comment: Ron, Windows 2000 reached end-of-life in 2010, and afaik a system running Windows 2000 cannot be considered PCI compliant.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

With Windows 2000/Server2003/Windows XP, the logs are stored in the `%SystemRoot%\System32\Config` directory, with an `.evt` extension.

With Server 2008/Vista and up, the log are stored in the `%SystemRoot%\system32\winevt\logs` directory, and have an `.evtx` extension. It's possible to [convert](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2007/10/12/windows-vista-and-exported-event-log-files/) old `.evt` files to the newer `.evtx` format

Within the Computer Manager you can also export them to a `.txt` or `.csv` file.

Comment: In case any future readers come here looking for the Windows Vista/7/Server2008 location, here it is: %SystemRoot%\system32\winevt\logs

Comment: @MilesErickson, thank you - from a future reader :)

Comment: can you please tell me which file hold the details for copy and paste done in system?

Comment: @NarendraJaggi There is no log of copy and paste operations. Why would such a thing even exist?!?